# feed links for custom post type pages

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, feed

I have a WP based site with a lot of pages based on custom post type. But I see a lot of 404-links in the Google Webmasters finished with /feed. It looks like default WP function, when WP adds /feed to any page and this should return history in RSS format. This is good. So my question is:

How I can make ".../feed" links working and show XML for comments on these special post type pages?

For example, my real page http://viva-games.ru/game/classic-japanese-monster-castle-2/feed returns 404, when http://viva-games.ru/game/classic-japanese-monster-castle-2 returns a page with comments. How I can make RSS link working and returning a page with XML with comments list?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why your website would generate so many pages ending with /feed, but perhaps this article can help you figure out what's going on. WordPress Feeds - http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: Hey Epsiloncool check this article i think it help you [feed](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-post-types-to-your-main-wordpress-rss-feed/)

Comment: Can you share how you register your custom post type? Is your `has_archive` set to `false`? - the feed is usually generated by default if it's `true`. You need to refresh your permalink settings when you change the setup. More about it [here in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters).

Comment: @birgire I am using CPT UI, and Has Archive is set to false for this post_type. http://epsiloncool.ru/i/E20141222_022031_001.png However I should to notice, ../feed links is NOT a revisions feed, but Comments feed. Please check source code of the page I've sent in the question ( http://viva-games.ru/game/classic-japanese-monster-castle-2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a bug in CPT UI plugin. There is no rewrite_rules apply at edit form submit stage. To have rewrite_rules finally applied, I have to show "edit post type" form (without submitting it) to have edited properties actually applied.

I've also described an issue in WP blog.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/apply-cpt-changes-immediately-on-submit?replies=1#post-6379853

Comment: So you're settling for `has_archive = true` regarding the feed links? PS: You can always visit the permalink settings page to refresh the rewrite rules, but I guess it's handy to have it included in the plugin you're using.

Comment: @birgire Yes, correct, I need to set up has_archive = true in plugin, but the problem was is I need to visit edit form to activate this rule. It is definitely a bug in CPT UI plugin and I've already reported this to plugin's author.

Comment: I hope it will be resolved in the plugin you're using, but the `has_archive=true` workaround is the same regardless if one is using a plugin or a custom code, because of the bug in the WordPress core.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem with the custom post type *feed* support when `has_archive` is `false`.

Check for example these tickets:

- #16415 [Don't require CPTs to have archives in order to have feeds](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16415)
- #24867 [Feeds for custom posts type can not be set independently of has_archive and supports => comments](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24867)

So regarding the native support, it looks like you might have to settle for `has_archive` as `true`, while these tickets are open ;-)

Comment: I found an interesting thing. If I switch HasArchive to true and then back to false, and save Custom Post Type in CPT-UI, ../feed links become working as well! But if I create new post type or modify existing without changing HasArchive select, ../feed links stopped working back again! Strange behaviour, but there is should be a bug somewhere. What do you think

Comment: I tried this with code, and I didn't see the same behaviour as you. I wonder when your /feed link is working, then your archive is working as well? Maybe the rewrite rules are not always flushed in your case?